# What is datetime2?

Tags: .net, sql, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, c#-3.0

I´ve got this in a INSERT statment to MSSQL 2008

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   The conversion of a datetime2 data
>   type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value.

Comment: The problem occurred when a used Entity Framework to INSERT a System.DateTime into my SQL2008 DB. I changed datatype in DB to datetime2 and now everything runs smoothly.

Comment: The problem had it´s begining with a logical error and the DateTime was never initialized ie I tried to insert 0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000

Comment: This one got me when I didn't initialize a DateTime in EF4 because I had a default value of GetDate() in the database.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Defines a date that is combined with a time of day that is based on 24-hour clock. datetime2 can be considered as an extension of the existing datetime type that has a larger date range, a larger default fractional precision, and optional user-specified precision.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx

Answer (score 21):

SQLServer's datetime datatype is a much smaller range of allowed values than .net datetime datatype. SQLServer's datetime type basically supports the gregorian calendar, so the smallest value you can have is 1/1/1753. In 2008 SQLServer added a datetime2 datatype that supports back to year 1 (there was no year 0). Sounds like you're trying to insert a datetime value that's before 1/1/1753 into a datetime (not datetime2) SQLServer column

Comment: Voted up for answering what the user really needed to know instead of the literal question :)

Answer (score 2):

From [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx):

> Defines a date that is combined with a time of day that is based on 24-hour clock. datetime2 can be considered as an extension of the existing datetime type that has a larger date range, a larger default fractional precision, and optional user-specified precision.

I had to check because I thought `datetime2` had some relation with `varchar2`. Apparently, no relation at all.

Put your code so we can guess what caused the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that your database table has a "DATETIME" or "SMALLDATETIME" column and you're trying to insert an out-of-range date?? DATETIME covers 1753-1-1 through 9999-12-31, while SMALLDATETIME covers 1900-1-1 through 2079-6-6 only.

The new SQL Server 2008 DATETIME2 data type will cover 0001-1-1 through 9999-12-31.

Marc

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when my database column was created as NOT NULL and I specifically specified a Nullable = true on my DateTime Property in my ADO.Entity framework EntityType.

To fix it I make the Nullable property = (None)