# conversion of a datetime2 data type to a smalldatetime EF6 MVC5

Tags: sql, entity-framework-6, type-conversion, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using MVC5 with EF6 code first. I have a table with a Date(Datum) column in both tabels(Kommunication and Itemannounce) with smalldatetime type and when I try to set the date with System.DateTime.Now in the column I get the following error:

> The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a smalldatetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value.The statement has been terminated.

I am aware of byte sizes and tried the following solution in my context:

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating( DbModelBuilder modelBuilder )
        {
        var annons = modelBuilder.Entity<Itemannounce> ( );
        annons.Property ( f => f.Datum ).HasColumnType ( "smalldatetime" );
        var komm = modelBuilder.Entity<Kommunication> ( );
        komm.Property ( f => f.Date ).HasColumnType ( "smalldatetime" );
        base.OnModelCreating ( modelBuilder );
        }
```

I still get same error. I tried to set the columns to NOT NULL without any luck. I am realy stuck in several days without to find a way out of this. Does anyone have a solution I have not tried?

Answer (score 0):

The minimum value for smalldatetime is `1900-01-01`

The minimum value for datetime2 is `0000-01-01`

Presumably,  what is happening here is that we are passing a datetime2 value into a smalldatetime column.  When datetime2 not been supplied and it is NON NULL then it will default to it's minimum value of `0000-01-01`.  This is well below the floor for smalldatetime.  It is out of bounds.  Inserting a value outside of the range of smalldatetime would yield the error message you are recieving.

> The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a smalldatetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value.The statement has been terminated.

There are many ways to solve this.  I would suggest updating the model to use datetime2.

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating( DbModelBuilder modelBuilder )
        {
        var annons = modelBuilder.Entity<Itemannounce> ( );
        annons.Property ( f => f.Datum ).HasColumnType ( "datetime2" );
        var komm = modelBuilder.Entity<Kommunication> ( );
        komm.Property ( f => f.Date ).HasColumnType ( "datetime2" );
        base.OnModelCreating ( modelBuilder );
        }
```

If you don't want to change the model then NULL checking could work as well.  [This similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443669/the-conversion-of-a-datetime2-data-type-to-a-smalldatetime-data-type-resulted-in) should give you a few ideas.

Comment: I tried All other options in previous posts without luck :(